# How to amplify a signal for piezo transducer from 1 Vpp to 200 Vpp at 400 kHz and 500 pF load

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, high-frequency, ultrasound, piezo

I'm a researcher working with phased ultrasonic transducer arrays.

I need to amplify a sine wave at 400 kHz and 1 Vpp to 200 Vpp. It has a capacitive load of 500 pF.

I'm little out of my op-amp depth, I researched audio amplifiers but the frequency is too high so any suggestions are greatly received.

Comment: Have you estimated how much power that will be?  200Vpp into the impedance of a 500 pF capacitance is like 50 watts.

Comment: Research commercial circuits for ultrasound transducers? You don't need to reinvent the wheel. But for your 50W load, some class AB design is probably needed, and you may be able to use audio concepts, some high voltage FETS in an output stage, or a LC tank resonator.

Comment: Is it a fixed 400kHz? If so, you can greatly reduce the driving power needed by using an inductor in parallel to resonate out the capacitance, leaving you with only the power dissipation to drive. Once you're into magnetics, you could use a transformer to drop the amplifier voltage.

Comment: @MadHatter Its the number of channels which is prohibitive for the commercial drivers. I actually have 2 sitting on my desk.

Comment: @Neil_UK yes, its fixed 400kHz, do you know a reference design you could point me to?

Comment: These transducers often have a very narrow bandwidth. Perhaps you can drive it with a square wave instead of a sine, which would be much simpler, cheaper, and more efficient: a pair of MOSFETs, a driver, done. You can also add an inductor, or use resonance. Can you check if this is possible?

Comment: Square wave is not a problem to drive the transducer, it was precise phase control which led me to using a sinewave and all pass filter. I'll do sine > sqaure wave > MOSFETs

Answer (score 4):

As this is a fixed frequency application, tuning out the capacitance with an inductor would improve things dramatically.

There's a choice to either do this in parallel, and drive the resulting tank at 200Vpp. Or it could be driven in series, with the benefit that if the transducer has a reasonable Q, the L and C together will achieve a significant voltage rise, and will turn an incident squarewave drive (easier than sine) into something that's very close to sinewave at the 500pF transducer.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fSaPwv.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This is only a sketch, there are a number of caveats.

The voltage magnification depends on the Q of your capacitive load. We don't know what the load is, so it could have a Q of 2, or 200. If the datasheet doesn't tell you, measure it. A Q of 10 means you would need only 20v on your driver.

Some form of tuning is required. This could be an adjustable core in the inductor, or a small value variable capacitor in parallel with your load. If the frequency is nominal, then you could servo the driving frequency to maximise the load voltage.

If your load won't tolerate the net DC offset that this half bridge gives you, then place a large (with respect to 500pF, say min 10nF) capacitor in series, or go to a full bridge configuration.

Re-reading your OP, this is for a phased array application. Because of the LC resonance, the phase at the transducer with respect to the driving squarewave phase is a quite vicious function of the tuning accuracy, with higher load Q meaning more vicious. You might need to feed back the actual transducer voltage to adjust the drive phase. You might use small tuning variations to effect a phase shift. Or the whole thing might be too unstable in phase that you have to go to a more direct drive for the transducers and just suck up the extra power that it needs.

Comment: Yes---tuning variations in each transducer may be the limiting factor.

Comment: Thanks for this I went for sinewave through allpass filter stages for precise phase control. A square wave is no problem to drive the transducer so I will convert sine to square wave for driving and use something like this solution but for each transducer. So long as the phase is constant this should work as I have a feedback loop control for phase. Many thanks

Comment: *So long as the phase is constant...*  That's the problem, the tuning to phase curve is very steep. Changes in temperature will detune the resonance. The question is whether the amount is acceptable for your application. This method of drive gives enough advantage that it's worth building one to measure the phase stability